# Animation doesn't work smoothly on increase in DOM size

Tags: javascript, css, animation, dom

i am applying animation on some of my content, animation is working fine if DOM size is small (approx elements are 1456) and if DOM size increases to 14556 elements then working of animation is not smooth and appears distorted.

I am using this toggle class function.

```
/ Toggle Full Screen/ normal screen mode of cell view /    
 function toggleFullScreen(){
      var zoomBtn = document.getElementById("cell-zoom-btn");
      var viewContainer  = document.getElementById("cellview");
      var viewClass      = viewContainer.className;

      //if view is already zoomed then bring it to normal and vice-versa
      if(viewClass.indexOf('zoom') > -1){
       $(viewContainer).removeClass('zoom');
       //changing icons on zoom btn expand icon --> <-- compress icon
       $(zoomBtn).removeClass('compress').addClass('expand');
      }
      else{
       $(viewContainer).addClass('zoom');
       $(zoomBtn).removeClass('expand').addClass('compress');
      }
 }
```

and using below css.

```
.cellmodal{
 height:95%;
 width:80%;
 margin:auto;
 position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1050;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    outline: 0;
 overflow-x:visible;
 box-sizing:border-box;
 display:none;
 -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.705, 0, 0.855, 1); / older webkit /
 -webkit-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.705, -0.600, 0.855, 1.190); 
   -moz-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.705, -0.600, 0.855, 1.190); 
     -o-transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.705, -0.600, 0.855, 1.190); 
        transition: all 400ms cubic-bezier(0.705, -0.600, 0.855, 1.190); / custom /
}

.cellmodal.zoom{
 height:98%;
 width:95%;
}
```